# How to run multiple mongodb databases on remote server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, centos

I have remote server on CentOS via ssh and I have one `test` mongo database on port 27017.

I would like to run another databases on the same port or maybe on another port to use two databases in my application at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple databases on one instance of mongod, there is no need to start up more than one instance if all you need is another database.

You cannot run more than one process on the same port, therefore you cant run another mongod on 27017.  You could start up another instance on a different port though, but I'm not sure why you would want to unless you're trying to create a replicaset.

Comment: agree with robjwilkins. All you have to do is when you get your db connection, use separate databases names so you will have different 'db' connections for different databases that run on the same port.

Answer (score 1):

I am running multiple mongodb databases using graphQL on one connection.
This should give you some idea:

**connection:**

```
import {MongoClient} from 'mongodb';
import assert from 'assert';
import graphqlHTTP from 'express-graphql';
const server_url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/contest_server';
const client_url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/contest_client';

// Establish connection to serverPool
module.exports = (app, PORT, ncSchema) => {
    MongoClient.connect(server_url, (serverErr, serverPool) => {
        assert.equal(null, serverErr);
        MongoClient.connect(client_url, (clientErr, clientPool) => {
            assert.equal(null, serverErr);
            app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
                schema: ncSchema,
                context: { serverPool, clientPool },
                graphiql: true
            }));

            app.listen(PORT, () => {
                console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`)
            });

            serverPool.collection("votes").count((err, count) => {
                console.log(count);
            });

            clientPool.collection("counts").count((err, count) => {
                console.log(count);
            });
        });
    });
};
```